# Starting two slapd processes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process, ldap, openldap

I'm working on restarting slapd process with minimum data loss and the task I was given was to start slapd process on port 400, reroute packets to it, and keep it alive until the one on default port (389) is alive again.

I've managed to stop the default one with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/slapd stop
```

and then to start another one with:

```
sudo slapd -h ldap://127.0.0.1:400 -g openldap -u openldap -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d
```

but if I try to do the above command after executing:

```
sudo slapd -h ldap://127.0.0.1:389 -g openldap -u openldap -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d
```

nothing happens.
Is it possible to have two slapds listening on different ports simultaneously?

Comment: I would question the requirement. If you can start the second slapd you can start the first, and they come up pretty quickly. I've been running OpenLDAP for 7-8 years and I haven't noticed any problem that would require this as a solution.

Comment: The thing is, this would be used in telecommunications where every second could mean thousands or tens of thousands rejected requests. But the more important part, slapd is only part of the larger LDAP suite, which will go into something like offline mode if it detects that slapd is not running. Restarting all of the suites' parts would take atleast 10-20 seconds. By starting another process, this could possibly be avoided.

Comment: I do not understand. If the emergency slapd that you start can come up in time, so can the real one.

Comment: The emergency slapd should start while the real one is running. Then the packets will get rerouted to the emergency one while the real one goes to restart. If there is no emergency (support) slapd, after the restart of the real one, there would be no slapds for some time, resulting in traffic loss.